# Linked css file in jade not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

This is what my directory structure looks like

```
--votingApp
    app.js
    node_modules
    public
      css
        mystyle.css
    views
      test.jade
      mixins.jade
```

I have written some general purpose blocks in mixins.jade. test.jade is the main file.'biolerplate','nav','nav item' are different blocks in mixins.
This is what test.jade looks like

```
include mixins
doctype html 
html(lang="en")
    head
        +boilerplate
        link(rel="stylesheet",type="text/css",href="../public/css/mystyle.css")
    body
        +nav("Voting app","navigation_menu")
            +nav_item("#","active") Home
            +nav_item("#") Signup
            +nav_item("#") Login
```

And this is my app.js file

```
var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var app=express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('view engine','jade');
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('test.jade');
});
app.listen(8000);
```

The problem is that the mystyle.css is not being loaded.The network option in the developer console of mozilla is showing that error 404 for the request for mystyle.css(request url-http://localhost:8000/public/css/mystyle.css)
What should I do please help?Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the relative path when loading your css, that's why you've defined your public directory as a [static resource](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Update your link line to this:

`link(rel="stylesheet",type="text/css",href="/public/css/mystyle.css")`

Comment: Thanks. It worked.Plus additional thanks for explaining the reason behind that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
link(rel="stylesheet",type="text/css",href="/css/mystyle.css")
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative path is never work with node.js so make it absolute like

```
link(rel="stylesheet",type="text/css",href="css/mystyle.css")
```

and you set your directory as public folder using following line

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

so discard writing public css in path.